# Inline models with images in admin model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models products and products images now I want to add product and images from the admin using one single form

Product Model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, null=True, blank=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey(BpBasic, default=BpBasic.get_admin_business().bp_id)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, related_name='product_created_by')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=False, related_name='product_updated_by')
```

Product Images Models

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/products/')
    primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, related_name='prod_image_created_by')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=False, related_name='prod_image_updated_by')
```

Product Image Inline Model

```
class ProductImageInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProductImage
    exclude = ('created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by', 'updated_by')
    extra = 1
```

Product Admin Model

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Products
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'category')
    fieldsets = [
        ('Product Details', {'fields': ['name', 'description']}),
        ('Product Category', {'fields': ['category']})
    ]
    inlines = [ProductImageInline]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        def set_user(instance):
            if not change:
                instance.created_by = request.user
            else:
                instance.updated_by = request.user
            instance.save()
        print formset
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        print list(instances)
        map(set_user, instances)
        instances.save()
        return instances

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.business = request.user.profile.business
        else:
            obj.updated_by = request.user
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

So I am having problem while saving the product

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ImageFieldFile found
```

I am getting the error above file saving. Please help!

The admin UI I have successfully generated 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problem with `__unicode__` method (or `__str__` if you use python3) in some of your models. It is a special methods for string representation of a model, so it should return a string.
For example:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Image created at {}'.format(self.created_at)
```